# $g$-function and D-brane tension

Tags: string-theory, renormalization, tachyon

In https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0009148  page 9 it is said that at the fixed points of the RG-flow of the open bosonic string , the $g$-function has stationary points which are the D-brane tensions. The authors claim that it coincides with the value of their tachyon potential $U(T)$ at those points. However, when defining the potential they say the Tachyon profile $T$ is dimensionless. But the tension is the energy per spatial volume. So how can this be true? In https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.08726 page 22 the authors claim that  $Z_{CFT}$ is proportional to the tension of the D25-brane. Again, $Z$ should not be dimensionful. Sen defines the Tachyon potential (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9911116) to have units of energy. Can someone explain what I am missing?

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question. For this question specifically, a self-contained explanation of what a "tachyon profile" or "tachyon potential" is would improve it a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will try to edit the question.